# Accounting for lower contrast when decreasing the opacity of dark background container

Tags: css, opacity, alpha, rgba, contrast

I am currently trying to fix some CSS. The specification I've got is that the background should be transparent, like this:

[image: Transparent]

But as you can see, when I set the background to transparent the white texts looks very washed out, as compared with:

[image: Opaque]

At the moment the text is set to fully white, fully opaque in the CSS:

```
.banner-content p {
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1) !important;
}
```

Can anyone suggest any CSS tricks to increase the apparent contrast, given that the text is already as white and as opaque as possible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set the opacity of a container like this:

```
#container {opacity:0.5;}
```

it affects the opacity of the container AND all of its children. So the font becomes 50% opaque too.

It seems like you really just want to give the container a translucent background, which you would do like this instead:

```
#container {background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);}
```

and that won't affect the text within that container.

Comment: I'll check this out and accept if it works. And here's me thinking it was just the contrast!

Comment: If that doesn't work, please include your HTML and CSS so I can see the exact structure.

Comment: Worked great. Thanks :).